# Featured Image id disappeared

Tags: plugins

The 'set featured image' box is not showing up at my 'Posts'. However i have added the following line `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` in my `functions.php` file therefore can someone make me aware about my mistake?

Comment: Is the right theme active ? (maybe you did this in another theme's functions.php)

Comment: Is the box for featured images ticked under "Screen Options"?

Comment: Yes right theme is active - Antoine Guillien

Comment: Yes it is ticked under "Screen Options". - s_ha_dum.

Answer (score 0):

When registering a custom post type you must say that your CPT accepts thumbnail:

```
$post_type = 'vehicles';
$supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail');

$args = array(
          [...]
          'supports' => $supports
      );
register_post_type($post_type, $args);
```